# Change text-color of php output on command prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, php, php-cli

Suppose I've a `php` file and I want to change text-colour of my output for a console based application...

```
<?php
$prompt = "What Is Your Name: ";
echo $prompt;
$answer =  "You Entered: " . rtrim( fgets( STDIN ));
echo $answer;
?>
```

I want to change text-colour of `$answer`.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: And how to **bold** output??

Comment: I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Now you can use 24-bit true color in terminal in Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

- The foreground escape sequence is `^[38;2;<red>;<green>;<blue>m`
- The background escape sequence is `^[48;2;<red>;<green>;<blue>m`
- `<red> <green> <blue>` range from 0 to 255 inclusive.
- The escape sequence `^[0m` returns output to default.

See RGB Color Codes [Chart](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm)

#### Demonstration of [24-bit true color in a script](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/tests/24-bit-color.sh):

[image]

Here is the modified script to produce colored output.

```
<?php
$prompt = "What Is Your Name: ";
echo $prompt;
$answer =  rtrim( fgets( STDIN ));
echo "\033[38;2;0;102;0m You \033[38;2;255;0;255m Entered: \033[38;2;255;255;0m $answer \033[0m \n";
?>
```

**Sample Output of the above script:**

[image: Sample output]

Comment: To make a string **bold as well as colored** one need to add `\033[1m` **at the beginning before the color part**. As mentioned by Jos.

Comment: Try `echo -en "\033[1mMy Bold Text\033[0m\n"` in a terminal. It will give bold output **My Bold Text**

Answer (score 7):

This is certainly possible using [ANSI escape codes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Colors):

```
<?php
echo "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
?>
```

will output "some colored text" in red and "some white text" in white (unless you chose different default colours for your terminal).

The characters `\033` indicate the start of an escape code. `[31m` is the colour red. `[0m` signifies the end of the coded fragment. For more colours, see [here](http://blog.lenss.nl/2012/05/adding-colors-to-php-cli-script-output/).

For other effects, such as bold:

`\033[1m bold text \033[0m`

see the first link. You can try out these codes on a command line by doing thing like:

```
echo -e "\033[1m bold text \033[0m"
```

Comment: Script to print 256 color combinations http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/9991f90/etc/colors.sh

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hard-coded sequences, you should use a library such as PHP [Ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ncurses.php) which will be more likely to work on more terminal types

The example from [`ncurses_color_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-color-set.php):

```
<?php
ncurses_init();

// If the terminal supports colors, initialize and set active color
if (ncurses_has_colors()) {
    ncurses_start_color();
    ncurses_init_pair(1, NCURSES_COLOR_YELLOW, NCURSES_COLOR_BLUE);
    ncurses_color_set(1);
}

// Write a string at specified location
ncurses_mvaddstr(10, 10, "Hello world! Yellow on blue text!");

// Flush output to screen
ncurses_refresh();

ncurses_end();
?>
```

From [`ncurses_has_colors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-has-colors.php):

> Checks whether the terminal has color capabilities. This function can be used to write **terminal-independent** programs.

[emphasis mine]

Use `ncurses_attr(NCURSES_A_BOLD);` for bold. Note that this function and the related ones are marked as experimental.

From [`ncurses_attron`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-attron.php)

> **Warning** This function is *EXPERIMENTAL*. The behaviour of this function,
>   its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a
>   future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.
>
> **Warning** This function is currently not documented; only its argument
>   list is available.

[emphasis theirs]

You may find other libraries. You should check to make sure they use terminal-independent techniques. I have found several that use hard-coded sequences instead.

Note that the command-line (shell) equivalent uses `tput` in order to be terminal independent. I include this information as a starting point for reference. They should be avoided.